# Displaying advanced graphs (with data from table)

Tags: info-visualisation, graphs

I have table with 5 columns that looks like this.

```
|Seller  | ArticleID | Count | Period | Site
--------------------------------------------
|User1   | BV1       | 3     | 2013-3 | Site1
|User1   | BV12      | 1     | 2013-3 | Site2
|User2   | BV3       | 2     | 2013-2 | Site1

+ 100 more rows
```

**Seller**: Our salesman
**Articleid**: The Product
**Count**: How many products
**Period**: During which year and month
**Site**: On what site

**The problem is: How should I display this data as a graph for easy display?**

I'm using **highcharts** for graph creation.

What I have done so far:

- Count as Y-axis
- Period as X-axis
- Line graphs in different colors that represents the different sites

So it looks similar to http://www.highcharts.com/demo/line-basic

But I'm missing the *Product* and the *Seller*.

Does anyone have a suggestion on how to display this or an UX-example that solves a similar problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a Business Intelligence developer myself, this is same question in my line of work, every time there are more dimensions than the graph can handle. As in your example, a line-chart is a two dimensional graph -- the common practice is to put the **measure** on the Y-axis, and one **dimension** each on the X-axis and on the graph lines.

To add more dimensions, the common practice is to have drop-downs that act as filters. The drop-downs may be multi-select or single-select, as per your need.

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fOxwLO.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

The drop-downs are responsive, meaning that the graph will be updated each time the value on the drop-down is changed.

Note however, that not all users of your system would like to see the same stuff on the same axes/filters. It is very good UX when you leave the axis and filter selection in the hands of the user itself. You could have the following in the settings menu for your graph:

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fsYg7g.png)</sup>

(It goes without saying that you must incorporate logic to avoid the same selection on two different axes/filters, as seen above with the disabled radio/checkbox options.)

It is worth mentioning here that other less common practices of accommodating more dimensions that a graph supports, is to use tabs or pagination in place of drop-downs. For example, in your example, you could have one tab for each product, and pagination under each tab for each seller type. You could either pre-render all of the graphs, or rendered a graph selectively when the user visits that tab/page. However, this approach is clumsy for a large number of dimensions, or when a particular dimension has a large number of entries (for instance, having a hundred tabs for a hundred products makes no sense).

Comment: That's an awesome approach, I will try that immiedately. Thank you!

Comment: @jocken: You're welcome! :)

Comment: @jocken: Thanks for accepting this answer. What was your final approach? If you improvised over this answer, it would be good to hear your feedback. :) Thanks!

Comment: @jocken: Is your comment missing a hyperlink? :P

Answer (score 1):

## Result

- I kept the Count in the Y-axis and the Period in the X-axis.
- I made 3 dropdowns, Product, Seller, Site.
- I decided, since our biggest challenge today is comparing our different sites and how it goes, to always have the site as static curve. So if I choose all sites, it divides the sites to different curves. Even if I choose a site the curve will still represent the site.
- Header became like this: **Sales - Mike Davis (1 year subscription-product)**
- I still haven't received any feedback due to holiday season so it might change in a few days.